# How to stop moving a file when an error is found in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP script that allows me to modify the tags of an XML file according to an SQL query and to move this file to a folder once it has been processed.

I added a condition on an error, if the SQL query returns nothing I send an email to be notified. It works well but the file with the error is still moved to the folder. I would like this one to stay in the base folder and the script to continue on the other files.

I tried to change the order of execution of the script several times but without success... can you help me? Thanks

And my script:

```
<?php
include "include/ODBCaccess.class.php";

$connect = odbc_connect("localhost","root","");
$dirname_source = "D:/xampp/htdocs/xml/";
$dirname_destination = "D:/xampp/htdocs/new_xml/";


$dir = opendir($dirname_source);
while($file = readdir($dir))
{
   $source_file =  $dirname_source.$file;
   $destination_file =  $dirname_destination."Order_".$file;
   if(is_file($source_file))
    {
        // echo $source_file;echo "<br>";
        // echo $destination_file;echo "<br>";
        
        $xml =new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
        $xml->load($source_file);
        
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
        foreach ($xpath->query("/Order/OrderLines") as $node)
        {
            $SKU_CODE = $node->getElementsByTagName("Code")->item(0)->nodeValue;
                      
            $query = "select GEAN from SKU where SKU='".$SKU_CODE."'";
            // echo $query; echo "<br>";
            $exec = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
            $result = odbc_fetch_array($exec);

            //ERROR    
            if ($result === false || $result['GEAN'] === null) {
                    // echo "GEAN not found for $SKU_CODE";
                    
                    //email part
                    $to = "test@gmail.com.com";
                    $subject = "Error GEAN";
                    
                    $message = "GEAN not found for $SKU_CODE in file $source_file";
                    
                    $header = "From:noreply@gmail.com \r\n";
                    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                    $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
                    
                    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
                    
                    if( $retval == true ) {
                        echo "Message sent successfully...";
                    }else {
                        echo "Message could not be sent...";
                    }
         
                }

                // $barcode = (string) $result['GEAN'];
                // echo $barcode; echo "<br>"; //9353970875729   
                            
                $node->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0)->nodeValue = "";
                $node->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0)->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($result['GEAN']));
                                
        }

        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        $xml->save($source_file);
        rename($source_file,$destination_file);
    }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `flag` with default value as `true`, and in case of an `error`, set it to `false`, and only save the file if the `flag` is `true`, like shown below:

```
<?php
include "include/ODBCaccess.class.php";

$connect = odbc_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$dirname_source = "D:/xampp/htdocs/xml/";
$dirname_destination = "D:/xampp/htdocs/new_xml/";


$dir = opendir($dirname_source);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    $source_file = $dirname_source . $file;
    $destination_file = $dirname_destination . "Order_" . $file;
    if (is_file($source_file)) {
        // echo $source_file;echo "<br>";
        // echo $destination_file;echo "<br>";

        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
        $xml->load($source_file);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

        $save = true; // default flag to allow saving
        foreach ($xpath->query("/Order/OrderLines") as $node) {
            $SKU_CODE = $node->getElementsByTagName("Code")->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $query = "select GEAN from SKU where SKU='" . $SKU_CODE . "'";
            // echo $query; echo "<br>";
            $exec = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
            $result = odbc_fetch_array($exec);

            //ERROR
            if ($result === false || $result['GEAN'] === null) {
                $save = false; // set flag to false in case of error to avoid saving

                // echo "GEAN not found for $SKU_CODE";

                //email part
                $to = "test@gmail.com.com";
                $subject = "Error GEAN";

                $message = "GEAN not found for $SKU_CODE in file $source_file";

                $header = "From:noreply@gmail.com \r\n";
                $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

                $retval = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

                if ($retval == true) {
                    echo "Message sent successfully...";
                } else {
                    echo "Message could not be sent...";
                }

            }

            // $barcode = (string) $result['GEAN'];
            // echo $barcode; echo "<br>"; //9353970875729

            $node->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0)->nodeValue = "";
            $node->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0)->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($result['GEAN']));

        }

        if ($save) { // save if the flag is true
            $xml->formatOutput = true;
            $xml->save($source_file);
            rename($source_file, $destination_file);
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

**Update:**

get array of all SKUs that have GEAN `null`, and check in loop if loop SKU exits in `array`, like shown below:

```
<?php
include "include/ODBCaccess.class.php";

$connect = odbc_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$dirname_source = "D:/xampp/htdocs/xml/";
$dirname_destination = "D:/xampp/htdocs/new_xml/";

$query = "select SKU from SKU where GEAN IS NULL";

$exec = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
$result = odbc_fetch_array($exec); // array of all SKUs where GEAN is null

$exec = odbc_exec($connect, "select SKU from SKU");
$allSKUs = odbc_fetch_array($exec); // array of all SKUs where GEAN is null

$dir = opendir($dirname_source);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    $source_file = $dirname_source . $file;
    $destination_file = $dirname_destination . "Order_" . $file;
    if (is_file($source_file)) {
        // echo $source_file;echo "<br>";
        // echo $destination_file;echo "<br>";

        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
        $xml->load($source_file);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

        $save = true; // default flag to allow saving
        foreach ($xpath->query("/Order/OrderLines") as $node) {
            $SKU_CODE = $node->getElementsByTagName("Code")->item(0)->nodeValue;

            //ERROR
            if (($result && in_array($SKU_CODE, $result)) || !in_array($SKU_CODE, $allSKUs)) { // if sku exits in result array, this means that its GEAN is null OR SKU is not present in the DB
                $save = false; // set flag to false in case of error to avoid saving

                // echo "GEAN not found for $SKU_CODE";

                //email part
                $to = "test@gmail.com.com";
                $subject = "Error GEAN";

                $message = "GEAN not found for $SKU_CODE in file $source_file";

                $header = "From:noreply@gmail.com \r\n";
                $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

                $retval = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

                if ($retval == true) {
                    echo "Message sent successfully...";
                } else {
                    echo "Message could not be sent...";
                }

            }

            // $barcode = (string) $result['GEAN'];
            // echo $barcode; echo "<br>"; //9353970875729

            $node->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0)->nodeValue = "";
            $node->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0)->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($result['GEAN']));

        }

        if ($save) { // save if the flag is true
            $xml->formatOutput = true;
            $xml->save($source_file);
            rename($source_file, $destination_file);
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Comment: Just a question, my SKU table contains a lot of records and the script takes a long time to go through the whole table. Is there a way to optimize it or do I have to modify it directly in my database instead?

Comment: Rather than getting SKU from DB in the loop, you can create an array of SKUs from DB using a single query before the loop, you can then compare the two `arrays` using `array_intersect`, and the rest of the process is the same. You can also add indexing to the SKU column to optimize as well.

Comment: So I keep the same query but I put the results in an array with two columns and then I compare the values in it with array_intersect?

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your requirement.

Comment: I just tested the code I think there is an error, it is when the SQL query does not return the GEAN code that there is an error. I tested and the file is moved + the following error "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given"

Comment: I assumed that there might b some results, updated the code to adjust if result is `false`

Comment: Same result... the mail is not sent and the file with the error is moved to the other folder..

Comment: updated the code, it should be fixed now

Comment: Always the same the file is moved and no mail. Do you need more info in my question?